# Destructuring objects from an array using map?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have wrote this simple code that destructures an array of objects to build new arrays from each key. I am learning ES6 and would like to refactor it into one line of code using destructuring but I dont fully understand how too.

```js
let candles = [{
  open: 1,
  high: 2,
  low: 0.5,
  close: 1.5,
  volume: 200
}];
let open = candles.map(x => x.open);
let high = candles.map(x => x.high);
let low = candles.map(x => x.low);
let close = candles.map(x => x.close);
let volume = candles.map(x => x.volume);

console.log(open, high, low, close, volume);
```

I am thinking it should look something along the lines of this?

```
let [open, high, low, close, volume] = candles.map(key => key.value);
```

But it is clearly wrong!
Thank you for help if someone can direct me the correct way on doing this!

Comment: You're mapping arrays to an arrays of arrays in the first snippet

Comment: Some before and after examples of sample data would greatly help explain what you're trying to do but as far as I can tell, you won't be able to do this with a one-liner

Comment: Ah, okay. That could explain why. But here is some sample data.
[ { open, high, low, close, volume}, {open, high, low, close, volume}, ...]

I am looking to convert that object of arrays a seperate array of all the opens, high, low, close, volume. So they each live in their own array after.

@Li357 candles is actually an array with objects.

Comment: As li357 stated, with the snippet running, you can see how your are creating arrays of arrays etc.

Comment: I took the liberty of making up data in the edit - please correct the snippet as necessary so we understand your needs.

Comment: `let candles = [{
  open: 1,
  high: 2,
  low: 0.5,
  close: 1.5,
  volume: 200
}];
let open = candles.map(x => x.open);
let high = candles.map(x => x.high);
let low = candles.map(x => x.low);
let close = candles.map(x => x.close);
let volume = candles.map(x => x.volume);`

Comment: Great - edit your question to change snippet to reflect that. That will provide an array with each open, each close, etc. as you desire. then we can work on the destructuring.

Comment: _"Some before **AND AFTER** examples..."_ you only addressed the first half

Comment: What is complete input and complete expected result?

Answer (score 3):

Although **map** is powerful and useful it is not the most effective strategy for your example case.

The *simplest* way to do this is to not use map at all. If you truly want a one-line solution try using **destructuring**:

```
let candles = [{
  open: 1,
  high: 2,
  low: 0.5,
  close: 1.5,
  volume: 200
}];

[{open, high, low, close, volume}] = candles
```

That simple one-liner is all you need:

```
console.log(open, high, low, close, volume)  // 1 2 0.5 1.5 200
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

```js
const candles = [{open: 1, close: 2, low: 3, high: 4, volume: 5}, {open: 6, close: 7, low: 8, high: 9, volume: 10}];

const result = candles.reduce((a, v) => {
  Object.keys(v).forEach(k => (a[k] = a[k] || []).push(v[k]));
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let candles = [ {
  open: 1,
  high: 2,
  low: 0.5,
  close: 1.5,
  volume: 200
} ]

const { open, high, low, close, volume } = candles.reduce( ( accumulator, item ) => {
    Object.keys( item ).forEach( key => {
        accumulator[ key ] = ( accumulator[ key ] || [] ).concat( item[ key ] ) 
    } )
    return accumulator
}, {} )
```

Answer (score 0):

So you should start with `reduce` first and return an object. Then you can use destructuring on that. Here's an example:

```
const candles = [{
  open: 1,
  high: 2,
  low: 0.5,
  close: 1.5,
  volume: 200
}, {
  open: 2,
  high: 3,
  low: 0.6,
  close: 1.4,
  volume: 300
}];

const reduction = candles.reduce((acc, candle) => {
  for (let key in candle) {
    if (!(key in acc)) {
      acc[key] = [];
    }

    acc[key].push(candle[key]);
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(reduction);
// { open: [ 1, 2 ],
//   high: [ 2, 3 ],
//   low: [ 0.5, 0.6 ],
//   close: [ 1.5, 1.4 ],
//   volume: [ 200, 300 ] }

const {open, high, low, close, volume} = reduction;

console.log(open, high, low, close, volume);
// [ 1, 2 ] [ 2, 3 ] [ 0.5, 0.6 ] [ 1.5, 1.4 ] [ 200, 300 ]
```

Comment: FYI: Hugo Silva's answer is the same technique. I broke mine out a bit to be easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: Thank you! I find it hard working with objects in es6.

Answer (score -1):

> **Array map destructuring**

**Simple trick:** `[{id:1, name:'awadhesh'}].map(({id, name}) => id + '---' + name);`

```
let candles = [{
 open: 1,
 high: 2,
 low: 0.5,
 close: 1.5,
 volume: 200
}];
let open = candles.map(({open}) => open);
let high = candles.map(({high}) => high);
let low = candles.map(({low}) => low);
let close = candles.map(({close}) => close);
let volume = candles.map(({volume}) => volume);

console.log(open, high, low, close, volume);
```

**log print = [1] [2] [0.5] [1.5] [200]**